# How do I keep the original color of a vector when exporting?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, color-conversion

I made a vector on Adobe Illustrator (v 24.1.2) and when I export it as a JPG or even if I open it as a PDF I notice I lose alot of the color. How do I prevent this from happening? 
Eventually I would like to blow this up and put it in a poster.
I have ensured to keep the color mode to CMKY.  Also when I saved it I made sure it was at high resolution.
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You would need to explain a bit more. You dont generally lose color when you save stuff. However quite many people arent aware that the secondary programs they use for checking arent profile aware, or then they themselves arent profile aware and have set the profile wrong or done a profile conversion at save.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Did you create the vector in CMYK mode in Illustrator, or are you only converting to CMYK when exporting? Please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/137729/edit) and add more information. Thanks. Note that RGB to CMYK conversion may be the problem here, but it's hard to tell without more info.

Comment: I am not sure if everyone is able to see my explanation below my question in which I explained the following:
I made a vector on Adobe Illustrator (v 24.1.2) and when I export it as a JPG or even if I open it as a PDF I notice I lose alot of the color. How do I prevent this from happening? Eventually I would like to blow this up and put it in a poster. I have ensured to keep the color mode to CMKY as I did my work. Also when I saved it I made sure it was at high resolution.

Comment: Hi @JobanaWeber. We see your explanation in the question, but need further information. Hard to tell what is going on but I can give two tips: 1. If you are making a vector illustration you shouldn't export a jpg which is *raster* (pixel) based. Save as a pdf instead to maintain the crispness. 2. As mentioned in another comment, you might be opening your document in a program which doesn't display CMYK properly. For example don't use Mac's Preview. Instead try opening your pdf in Acrobat.